# Pip throws 'Error initializing plugin EntryPoint(name='macOS', value='keyring.backends.macOS', group='keyring.backends')'

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm running python 3.8 under Pop!_OS and noticed a weird reoccurring error when running various `pip` commands like `install` or `list --outdated`. The full error states:

```sh
Error initializing plugin EntryPoint(name='macOS', value='keyring.backends.macOS', group='keyring.backends').
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 203, in _load_plugins
    init_func = ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring.backends.macOS'
```

The command's functionality appears to be unaffected by this but it irritates me nonetheless and I have been unable to find anything about this sort of error.
So my question is, **why is this error triggered by various basic pip commands, why is it about macOS and how do I fix it?**

Comment: This error is a lot more persistent on my machine. Neither a new terminal nor a restart will fix it. Also I can't uninstall or reinstall anything because any pip command will just reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was happening to me also after trying to update keyring. I properly updated it afterwards and it persisted.
My issue solved itself after I opened a new terminal window....

Comment: how does one update the keyring?

Comment: For me I had to restart my computer :-\

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by reinstalling the python keyring package

```python
pip uninstall keyring
pip install keyring
```

Updating the package may also work

```python
pip install keyring -U
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened because I conda activate my env from an existing env.

This raised the error

```
$ conda activate my_env1
(my_env1) $ conda activate my_env2
(my_env2) $ pip install <package>
```

And this fixed it

```
$ conda activate my_env1
(my_env1) $ conda deactivate
$ conda activate my_env2
(my_env2) $ pip install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
python -m keyring --disable
```

This should fix (or create if missing) the file `$HOME/.config/python_keyring/keyringrc.cfg` (use `python -c "import keyring.util.platform_; print(keyring.util.platform_.config_root());` to check what's the right path for you).